# PHP Subtract multidimensional arrays based on 2 values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to subtract the qt from two arrays based on id and type, keeping the array complete.

How do I do in php to be able to subtract these arrays?

I have 2 arrays:

=> this is the first array with multiple key "down"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [loc] => 1
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [loc] => 1
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 34
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [loc] => 2
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 5
        )
        
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [loc] => 3
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 45
        )
        
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [loc] => 9
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 3
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [loc] => 3
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 99
        )
)
```

=> this is the second array with multiple key "up"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [loc] => 1
            [type] => up
            [qt] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [loc] => 3
            [type] => up
            [qt] => 27
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [loc] => 9
            [type] => up
            [qt] => 3
        )
)
```

=> I need cubtract "qt" (if "id" and "loc" are the same then subtract the "qt")

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [loc] => 1
            [type] => total
            [qt] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [loc] => 1
            [type] => total
            [qt] => 34
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [loc] => 2
            [type] => total
            [qt] => 5
        )
        
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [loc] => 3
            [type] => total
            [qt] => 18
        )
        
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [loc] => 9
            [type] => total
            [qt] => 0
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [loc] => 3
            [type] => down
            [qt] => 99
        )
)
```

Comment: So what are you stuck on? Not seeing any code. Loop or maybe `array_map`?

Comment: Maybe try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160915/php-sum-values-with-the-same-key A lot of similar answers on here. PHP array functions can do a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
function findMatch($array, $id, $loc)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item["id"] == $id and $item["loc"] == $loc) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$total = [];
foreach($down as $d) {
    $matched = findMatch($up, $d["id"], $d["loc"]);
    if($matched !== false){
        $total[] = array_replace($d, [
            "type" => "total",
            "qt" => ($d["qt"] - $up[$matched]["qt"])
        ]);
    } else {
        $total[] = array_replace($d, ["type" => "total"]);
    }
}
print_r($total);
```